# Failed to connect to repository Jenkins setup version 2.249.1

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-cli, jenkins-github-plugin, jenkins-git-plugin

Installed Jenkins and git on windows machine. when trying to set URL under source code management following error shown:
PATH enviornment variable
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin
Jenkins->ManageJenkins->global tool configuration-> git path set it as C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git

while trying to set URL as below:

https://github.com/User/EmployeeApp error shown below:
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git ls-remote -h https://github.com/user/EmployeeApp/ HEAD

Please help me to resolve this error !

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding this
Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> global tool configuration

under Git
PATH to executable git -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe

cheers!